# How to place a button at the same height as 2 dropdowns

Tags: bootstrap-5

I would like the button to be placed at the same height as the other elements. But I don't know how to do this. I'm lost in the blocks...

[btn print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeA3C.jpg)

How could I place the button at the same height as the dropdowns?

Here is an idea of my code below

```css
.wrapper-component {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML CSS JS</title>
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="mt-5 home-content wrapper-component ">
         <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-auto">
                     <!-- Type -->
                     <label for="type" class="col-form-label">TYPE</label>
                  </div>
                  <select class="form-select" style="max-width: 240px">
                     <option selected disabled value="">Choice an item</option>
                     <!-- ALL -->
                     <option [value]="'ALL'">ALL</option>
                     <!-- IN -->
                     <option [value]="'IN'">IN</option>
                     <!-- OUT -->
                     <option [value]="'OUT'">OUT</option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="col-auto">
                     <label for="status" class="col-form-label">STATUS</label>
                  </div>
                  <select class="form-select" style="max-width: 240px">
                     <option selected disabled value="">Choice a status</option>
                     <!-- ALL -->
                     <option [value]="''">ALL</option>
                     <!-- ENCODE -->
                     <option [value]="'1'">ENCODE</option>
                     <!-- DELETE -->
                     <option [value]="'8'">DELETE</option>
                     <!-- DONE -->
                     <option [value]="'9'">DONE</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <div class="float-end">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                     <!-- Print -->
                     <button class="btn btn-secondary ml-2" (click)="printPage()">Print</button>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add another `<div class="col-auto">` with the button inside.

See the snippet below.

```css
.wrapper-component {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>HTML CSS JS</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="mt-5 home-content wrapper-component ">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-auto">
            <!-- Type -->
            <label for="type" class="col-form-label">TYPE</label>
          </div>
          <select class="form-select" style="max-width: 240px">
            <option selected disabled value="">Choice an item</option>
            <!-- ALL -->
            <option [value]="'ALL'">ALL</option>
            <!-- IN -->
            <option [value]="'IN'">IN</option>
            <!-- OUT -->
            <option [value]="'OUT'">OUT</option>
          </select>
          <div class="col-auto">
            <label for="status" class="col-form-label">STATUS</label>
          </div>
          <select class="form-select" style="max-width: 240px">
            <option selected disabled value="">Choice a status</option>
            <!-- ALL -->
            <option [value]="''">ALL</option>
            <!-- ENCODE -->
            <option [value]="'1'">ENCODE</option>
            <!-- DELETE -->
            <option [value]="'8'">DELETE</option>
            <!-- DONE -->
            <option [value]="'9'">DONE</option>
          </select>
          <div class="col-auto ms-auto">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary ml-2" (click)="printPage()">Print</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I would like the button to be on the right, , I tried `pull-right` but it doesn't work? I do not understand why? `<button class="btn btn-secondary pull-right ml-2" (click)="printPage()">`

Comment: I edited my answer. Add the class `ms-auto`.

Comment: Thank it works. Thank you 10000 times.